# Passing a variable to the width argument in read.fwf

Tags: r

The problem I am trying to solve is that I need to read multiple fixed width files each with potentially different column widths. So I want to loop through some files and match it with the correct schema and read the data with the splits in the correct place.

I haven't found a way of passing in a schema file to read.fwf or read_fwf , and don't want to have to hard code, so I have pulled the columns lengths into a variable simplified code below

```
widths <- "10,5,5,10"
widths <- noquote(widths)

read_fwf("file.txt", fwf_widths(c(widths)))
```

but get an error as below

```
Error in abs(widths) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function Error in abs(widths) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Is it possible to pass the variable in this way or will it always read it as text.

Comment: Maybe: `read.fwf("file.txt", c(10,5,5,10))`

Comment: or if *widths* is given as character: `read.fwf("file.txt", as.integer(strsplit(widths, ",")[[1L]]))`

Comment: @GKi This last one looks to have worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @GKi does the job.

read.fwf("file.txt", as.integer(strsplit(widths, ",")[[1L]]))